# Using modulus operator on a char in C

Tags: c, caesar-cipher, modulo

I am trying to mod a char in c by using the following:

```
int shift = 1;    
c = (c + shift ) % 26;
printf("c= %c \n",c);
```

The variable c is a lowercase english character between a-z. When I try to print out the char c using the above code, I get the following:

```
c=
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 0-25 are not visible characters in ascii.

Comment: The letter c doesn't have a value of less than 26.  You might take a look at an ascii chart and see if that helps.

Comment: You might want to add an `'a'` (or `'A'`) to that.

Comment: You want `'a' + (c - 'a' + shift) % 26` if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Shift it by `'a'` or `'A'`. Then you'll always get a character that's part of the alphabet:

```
int main(){
    unsigned i;
    for(i=0;;i++)
        printf("i=%c\n", 'a'+i%26);

 }
```

prints:

```
i=a
i=b
i=c
i=d
i=e
i=f
i=g
i=h
i=i
i=j
...
```